# Read contents from PDF File in Python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm trying to read the following PDF and I can't do it. Either I get unreadable characters or the UnicodeDecodeError. Some solution for that.

```
import PyPDF2
import codecs 

rutas = 'file.pdf'

pdf_file = open(rutas,'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
page_content = page.extractText()
print(page_content.encode('utf-8'))
b'\n\n\xcb\x98\xcb\x87\xcb\x86\xcb\x99\xcb\x9d\xcb\x98\xcb\x9b\xcb\x98\xcb\x87\n\xcb\x9a\xcb\x9c \xcb\x9c!"#\xcb\x98$%&&\xcb\x98\'\xcb\x98()\xcb\x9c*"*\xcb\x98*+\xcb\x98\x


temp = textract.process(rutas).decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2075: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [tika](https://tika.apache.org/) to extract the text:

```
from tika import parser

PdfPath = 'file.pdf'
raw = parser.from_file(PdfPath)
textPDF = raw['content']
print(textPDF)
```

To get specific page contents you can split the file into separate pages/sections using PyPDF2 and use this method on splitted pages.